# Why is setCursor() not working?

Tags: java, user-interface, compiler-errors, cursor, awt

I am testing a new aspect of java, by attempting to make a custom cursor for my game, but it seems as I have run into a problem where in my code *setCursor();* is bringing up a compiler error, for the reason that it is not seen as a proper piece of code. I was following tutorials and different guides, which all led to the same problem and I have found no answer for my query.

```
Toolkit toolKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = toolKit.getImage(getClass().getResource("/res/cursor.png"));
Point point = new Point(0, 0);
Cursor cursor = toolKit.createCustomCursor(img, point, "Cursor");
setCursor(cursor);
```

Hope someone might be able to assist me, thanks in advance.
Notes:

- I am running the latest JRE as of now (1.8).
- The compiler error being    recieved is as follows:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem: 
>         The method setCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type Main

Comment: *"setCursor(); is not understood as anything"* - what does that mean?  Are you getting a compiler or runtime error? What GUI framework are you using (Swing/JavaFX/...)? Consider using `ImageIO.read` over `Toolkit.getImage`, it will throw an exception when the image can't be loaded rather the failing silently

Comment: I mean I am getting a compiler error. I am using Swing for my GUI.

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: I hope the edit is a bit more clear

Comment: [`setCursor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor-java.awt.Cursor-) is a metod defined in `Component` - you will need an instance of a `Component` (like `JPanel`) to use it

Comment: I do have a JPanel used instead of the default frame decoration. Is that what is expected? If not the application is all in a JFrame (or *application window* as said in the Swing project creator).

Comment: Then, you need to call `setCursor` with the instance of `JPanel` - A runnable example would make it easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved thanks to MadProgrammer's last comment:

> Then, you need to call `setCursor` with the instance of `JPanel` - A runnable example would make it easier.

The problem I had encountered was that I had used a JFrame as my container, instead of a JPanel. To fix my previous code I changed my main container to a JPanel, which in return allowed me to use: `JPanelName.setCursor();`

Edit: With further testing, I also found that a JFrame can still be used the same way as previously mentioned. The problem with my code above was that I was calling for it as `JFrame.setCursor();`, which was a static call to a non-static method. This then gave me the impression that I should only use `setCursor();` (As seen in my query above). Hope this helps anyone who might have some misunderstandings on the `setCursor();` method. Thanks again to MadProgrammer for solving the problem.